# Jquery ui js return

Tags: php

i use jquery ui js.

When i return result i am doing this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,value FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE :keyword');
$keyword = "%".$data."%";
$stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();   
while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $user['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($user['column']));
    $user['id']=(int)$user['id'];
    $user_set[] = $user;
}
```

And the returned array:

```
[{"id":1,"column":"user","value":"user"}]
```

I just set $user[id] and $user['value'], but there are three things returned , why?

Greetings!

Comment: What does jquery/jquery-ui/javascript have to do with anything here? Your title is completely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       ^^^^^
```

Comment: this snippet does actually populate $user array, if you didn't notice